# What are the intervals(?) in the end of yfinance timeindex?

Tags: pandas, time-series, yfinance

Downloading data from Yahoo finance via the library yfinance returns a data-frame with a time-index

```
df = yf.download("MSFT ORCL", interval="30m", period="20D")
```

The index seems a bit unusual.

```
                                Adj Close             ...   Volume         
                                 MSFT       ORCL  ...     MSFT     ORCL
Datetime                                          ...                  
2021-10-25 09:30:00-04:00  307.415009  98.349998  ...  3007643   583876
2021-10-25 10:00:00-04:00  308.109985  97.879997  ...  1295458   593084
2021-10-25 10:30:00-04:00  307.980011  98.120003  ...   962431   268932
2021-10-25 11:00:00-04:00  308.209991  98.184998  ...   816024   204434
2021-10-25 11:30:00-04:00  308.065002  98.320000  ...   804070   145182
                               ...        ...  ...      ...      ...
2021-11-19 13:30:00-05:00  343.250000  94.360001  ...   758614   261011
2021-11-19 14:00:00-05:00  342.894989  94.004997  ...   587500   270425
2021-11-19 14:30:00-05:00  342.932007  94.065002  ...   590121   296746
2021-11-19 15:00:00-05:00  343.296814  94.044998  ...   832597   311972
2021-11-19 15:30:00-05:00  343.029999  93.970001  ...  2250862  1012153
```

What is the -05:00 or -04:00 in the index. I know I can't compare it to a normal timestamp with the same value.

```
test = pd.Timestamp(2021, 10, 25, 9,30)
```

Is not equal to the index in the data frame with the value "2021-10-25 09:30:00-04:00".

Comment: Looks like timezone information, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html

Comment: It is a time zone value, so if you don't need it, you can remove it with the following code.`df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index);df.index = df.index.tz_localize(None)`